ScreenFlow LWC configurator update Apex-Defined Input
I have a custom LWC that has another custom LWC as configuration editor of a flow. This LWC has a property I set as Apex-Defined:
<property name="source" type="apex://Source" label="Source"></property>
That it's reference as @api in both LWCs.
The ApexClass Source looks like this:
public class Source {
    @AuraEnabled public List<String> value {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public Boolean multipleValues {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public Integer multipleValuesLimit {get;set;}
    public Source(){}
}

And this is the event I dispatch in order to update my property:
this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('configuration_editor_input_value_changed', {
        bubbles : true,
        composed : true,
        cancelable : false,
        detail : {
            newValue : {
                value : ['a','b'],
                multipleValues : true,
                multipleValuesLimit : 5
        },
        name : 'source',
        newValueDataType : 'Apex'
    }
}))

And it doesn't throw any errors when configuring the LWC inside a Screen of the ScreenFlow but as soon as I try to save I get the following error:

And no further information. I've been checking the documentation and found no examples on how to accomplish this.
Is there something I'm missing or doing wrong?
Regards,
